# Spring batch job to process a dynamic set of files parallely

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to design a spring batch job which I want to process a dynamic set of files parallely. Meaning when the batch job itself is started, the number of files to process is not known - the files are available dynamically. The job should run and continue to process the files parallely as and when a new file arrives,till it has finished processing all files.

I have gone through the spring batch project page, and from my understanding it looks like Multi-threaded Step is suitable for my case. But the thing that I am not sure of is whether it can support dynamic availability of files to be processed?

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.
Thanks and regards,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here:

1. [`MultiResourceItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html) - This `ItemReader` wraps an `ItemWriter` like the `FlatFileItemReader` and loops through the resources provided via an expression.
2. Partitioning - This option is better for parallel processing of files.  Using the `MultiResourcePartitioner`, you can execute files in parallel with all the restartability, etc features you'd normally get with Spring Batch.

You can read more about partitioning in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html

Comment: Thanks Micheal, on further reading about Partioning, if my understanding is correct, then the splitter that does the partioning of the data to be processed in parallel, requires that the data is available and known at the runtime - meaning it does not support dynamically available data. In my case, files might keep coming in, and as long as the job is running, the moment it finds a new file has arrived, it need to pick that file and start processing it in parallel to the ones it is already processing. Kindly let me know how this can be achieved. Thanks

Comment: For what you are describing, we typically recommend a slightly different approach.  Instead of having a single batch job instance that is running for a long period of time, we typically have a Spring Integration poller polling for new files and launching batch jobs as they come in.